# ブートローダーが書き込めない

Tags: spresense

Arduino IDEを使って、SonyのSpresenseにブートローダーを書き込むことがどうしてもできません。デバイスも認識されていますが、「マイコンボードにブートローダーを書き込んでいます」と下部に表示され、長い時間が経過した後、「ブートローダーの書き込む中にエラーが発生しました。」というメッセージが表示されます。動作環境は以下の通りです。
　Windows10
　Arduino 1.8.7

念のため、recoverytoolによるリカバリーも行ってみましたが、「.....」という表示の後、そのまま停止してしまう状況です。製品不具合以外に何か原因が考えられますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご不便をお掛けして、誠に申し訳ございません。

お手数ですが、症状などを添えてお買い上げいただいた販売店にお問い合わせいただけるでしょうか。どうぞ、よろしくお願いいたします。