# Spresenseにブートローダーを書き込もうとすると、「実行中の Windows のバージョンと互換性がありません」エラーがすぐに出る

Tags: spresense

Arduino IDEを使って、SonyのSpresenseにブートローダーを書き込むことがどうしてもできません。デバイスも認識されていますが、別質問の「[ブートローダーが書き込めない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48610/19110)」質問内容とは違い、

1. ツール→ボード→"Spresense"を選択
2. ツール→ポートで上述のCOMポートを指定 "COM6(Spresense)"
3. ツール→書込装置→"Spresense Firmware Updater"を選択
4. ツール→"ブートローダを書き込む"
   を選択すると即、ArduinoIDE画面下部の黒画面メッセージ部分に

```
Arduino：1.8.12 (Windows Store 1.8.33.0) (Windows 10), ボード："Spresense, MainCore, Disabled, 115200"
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\SPRESENSE\tools\spresense-tools\1.5.1/flash_writer/windows/flash_writer.exe": CreateProcess error=216, このバージョンの %1 は、実行中の Windows のバージョンと互換性がありません。コンピューターのシステム情報を確認してから、ソフトウェアの発行元に問い合わせてください。
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at processing.app.helpers.ProcessUtils.exec(ProcessUtils.java:26)
    at cc.arduino.packages.Uploader.executeUploadCommand(Uploader.java:129)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.runCommand(SerialUploader.java:383)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.burnBootloader(SerialUploader.java:372)
    at processing.app.Editor.lambda$handleBurnBootloader$61(Editor.java:2366)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=216, このバージョンの %1 は、実行中の Windows のバージョンと互換性がありません。コンピューターのシステム情報を確認してから、ソフトウェアの発行元に問い合わせてください。
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 6 more
ブートローダの書き込み中にエラーが発生しました。
「ファイル」メニューの「環境設定」から
「より詳細な情報を表示する：コンパイル」を有効にすると
より詳しい情報が表示されます。」
```

のメッセージが表示されてブートローダーを書き込むことがどうしてもできません。
尚、質問記載上、"C:\Users\・・・・・の部分は"C:\Users\xxxxxxxx・・・　に置き換えております。

試行環境はWindows10 32Bit、Windows7 32Bit（其々別のPC）で行っても結果は同じです。
またArduinoIDEは 1.8.10で行っても1.8.12で行っても結果は同じです。
ちなみに、この環境で今迄ArduinoUNO、ArduinoDUEの開発を行っており、別に問題は有りませんでした。

何か設定上の問題でしょうか？
又は製品不具合以外に何か原因が考えられますでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Spresense Arduino IDEには、32bit版Windows用と64bit版Windows用が用意されているようですが、64bit版のArduino IDEを使っているという事はないですか？（テストしていらっしゃるのが、どちらも32bit版のWindows 7とWindows10なので、確認のためにお聞きします。

Comment: 有難うございます。Spresenseに関して初めてですので、初期的なご質問させて頂きます。 Arduino IDEに関しては、1.8.10、1.8.12共にWindows10、及びWindows7とも32Bit版にてArduinoUNO、ArduinoDUEの開発に使っておりましたので32Bit版と認識しておりました。「64bit版のArduino IDEを使っているという事はないですか？」との事は、Arduino IDEのツール、ボードマネージャーで追加したSpresenseの部分の事を言われているのでしょうか？宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: Arduino IDEのツール、ボードマネージャーで追加したSpresenseの部分の事である場合、「Spresense Reference Board by Spresence Community バージョン1.5.1」しか表示されず、他（64Bit版、32Bit版など）の選択は有りませんでした。Spresense Arduino IDEには、32bit版Windows用と64bit版Windows用をどの様に選択すればよいのでしょうか？宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「32bit版 Linux には対応していません。」との記述は有りますが、Window 32Bitには対応していないとの記述は見当たりません。何方かWindow10 32Bit環境でSpresense Arduino IDEを使われている方はおられませんか？宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 大変お騒がせ致しました。私の見間違いか、Sonyドキュメントの「Spresense Arduino スタートガイド」1.1. サポートしているプラットフォームの部分に•Windows 8.1/10 (64bit版)と有りますが、最近まで(64bit版)の部分は無く、また「32bit版 OS には対応していません。 」の部分は「Linux32bit版 OS には対応していません。」となっていた様に思いました。古い情報をみていたかもしれません。お手数をお掛け致しますた。

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

ご不便をお掛けしてしまって申し訳ございません。
ご質問の、Spresenseへのブートローダ書き込み機能についてお答えいたします。

ドキュメント上誤解を与える表現となってしまっておりましたが、
現在Spresenseの開発環境は64Bit版OSのみサポートしております。
32Bit版Windowsでは正しく動作いたしません。

申し訳ございませんが、64Bit版のWindowsをご利用ください。

ドキュメントについても修正いたしました。
[1.1. サポートしているプラットフォーム](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_set_up_ja.html#_%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0)

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。64Bit版のWindowsでの開発環境を新たに準備いたします。